# If there is more members in array "a[]" then "b[]" i get error

Tags: java, arrays

If i put this `int a[]={2,5,8,8,9,4,9,8,9,6,4,7};`, I get the following error  :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

How to solve this?

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[]={2,5,8,8,9,4,9,7};


        int b[]={1,5,8,5,6,2,9,8};

        int samenumber= 0;

        for(int i=0; i<a.length;  i++){ 
            if( a[i]==b[i]) {
                samenumber++;
            }


        }       
        System.out.println("The same numbers in the same index: "+ samenumber);         

    }

}
```

Comment: Either the size of both array should be same or you have to alter the loop to iterate till the least size (min of size a & b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only want to iterate over the indices that exist in both arrays,
so you should change the loop's stopping condition :

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length && i<b.length;  i++){ 
    if( a[i]==b[i]) {
        samenumber++;
    }
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<Math.min(a.length,b.length); i++){ 
    if( a[i]==b[i]) {
        samenumber++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3527161 My suggested code doesn't produce errors, regardless of the lengths.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int a[]={2,5,8,8,9,4,9,8,9,6,4,7};

    int b[] = { 1, 5, 8, 5, 6, 2, 9, 8 };

    int samenumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (b.length > i) {
            if (a[i] == b[i]) {
                samenumber++;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("The same numbers in the same index: " + samenumber);

}
```